# javascript or ajax actionlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I am working with mvc4 and new to working with it. I have a question around the Ajax ActionLink.

I have a long list of products, with each, there is an add to bag button. In the past I would use jquery to bind a click event to this button and then use javascript to make a server side request to a controller action.

I want all interaction to not cause a full page postback.

I am wondering is it best to follow my approach with javascript or use the Ajax ActionLink? What are the pros and cons of either approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are same.

1. Ajax ActionLink : less to write, works with conjuction Jquery un-obtrusive.  Not much control on the markup.
2. HtML Link + Jquery Ajax call : will you give full control on the click event, you can add extra options to it.

Comment: Following clicking on ajax actionlink, can a json object be returned back to a javascript function, if its successful? I want to take the json and use knockout to bind it to a table.

Comment: @amateur http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020705/ajax-beginform-calls-action-returns-json-how-do-i-access-json-object-in-my-on