# ASP.NET MVC client valitation on ui-dialog?

Tags: json, jquery-ui, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(kod => kod.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessage("Name","Client Error Message")
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult JsonAddCustomer(Customers customer, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (customer.Name.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Server Error Message");
        }

        //Eğer hata yoksa veri tabanına kayıt yapılıyor.
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                CusOpp.InsertCustomer(customer);
                return Json(new { success = true, redirect = returnUrl });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");
            }
        }

        return Json(new { errors = GetErrorsFromModelState() });
    }
```

I want to write validation error message. I did this like above, but `@Html.ValidationMessage("Name","Client Error Message")` does not work. In fact, I was already expecting it.

I want to show like this statement's result: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name)` ,but I cant use this, because I used entity-data-model.

Should I add `[Required]` statement to data-model classes or any way that I do this. Sorry for bad explanation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return PartialViews instead of JSON in this case. Only in the case of success you could return JSON:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonAddCustomer(Customers customer, string returnUrl)
{
    // Warning: the following line is something horrible => 
    // please decorate your view model with data annotations or use
    // FluentValidation.NET to validate it. 
    // Never write such code in a controller action.
    if (customer.Name.Trim().Length == 0)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Server Error Message");
    }

    //Eğer hata yoksa veri tabanına kayıt yapılıyor.
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            CusOpp.InsertCustomer(customer);
            return Json(new { success = true, redirect = returnUrl });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error");
        }
    }

    return PartialView(customer);
}
```

Now inside the success callback of your AJAX request you can test whether the POST action succeeded or not:

```
success: function(result) {
    if (result.redirect) {
        // we are in the success case => redirect
        window.location.href = result.redirect; 
    } else {
        // a partial view with the errors was returned => we must refresh the DOM
        $('#some_container').html(result);

        // TODO: if you are using unobtrusive client side validation here's 
        // the place to call the $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form"); method in order 
        // to register the unobtrusive validators on the newly added contents
    }
}
```

Here's a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8922646/29407) that you might also read through.

Comment: There are a lof of column to validate in my model. So I dont want to write "if statements" for validation. I there any solution like public class FeedBack
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Feedback")]
    public string Feedback { get; set; }
}

Comment: Yes, exactly, you should use Data Annotations on your view model and decorate the corresponding properties with the necessary attributes instead of writing those if conditions inside your controller action.

Comment: I use entity-model. How I can do this?

Comment: Oh, no, that's a very wrong approach. You should never pass domain entities to views. You should work with view models which are classes that you specifically design for the requirements of your views.

Comment: On which note, I started to use AutoMapper recently for converting between my data models and my view models. I thought it worth mentioning for the OP should they be wondering about conversions.

Comment: @JamieDixon, thanks. That's an excellent remark about AutoMapper. I use it all the time in all projects.

Answer (score 0):

Your Idea with the Required annotation on the model is a good approach. You can set a Error Message on the Required annotation.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")]
```

and remove your if in your action..this:

```
if (customer.Name.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name", "Server Error Message");
        }
```

the **ModelState.IsValid** will do the job for you on the client and server side.

And use your **@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name)** in your view

Comment: This is my problem I use entity-data-model. Where do I write [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a name")] ??

Comment: o.k  a View Model is the key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735635/real-example-of-tryupdatemodel-asp-net-mvc-3/7777059#7777059

Comment: I dont write classes myself. There are from entity-data-model. Should I write my model?