# How to use Ajax.BeginForm MVC helper with JSON result? Reference data in JSON Result

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

In the post [How to use Ajax.BeginForm MVC helper with JSON result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304233/how-to-use-ajax-beginform-mvc-helper-with-json-result) Joel references a solution as follows:

```
function onTestSuccess(data, status, xhr) { 

    console.log("data", data); 
    console.log("xhr", xhr); 
    console.log("status", status); 

    // Here's where you use the JSON object 
    //doSomethingUseful(data); 
}
```

How do I reference elements in the JSON object "data" in my code?
My console log shows the following:
LOG: data{"success":true,"uri":"/Image/Confirm2?category=foo"}

I am trying to use the value of "uri" in my jquery code.  I've tried:

console.log("uri", data.uri);

but get the folowing as a result:

LOG: datauriundefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onTestSuccess(data, status, xhr) { 
    var uri = data.uri;
    // uri = '/Image/Confirm2?category=foo' at this stage 
    // so you could do something useful with it
}
```

Also for this to work you need to use the `OnSuccess="onTestSuccess"` setting in your AjaxOptions when setting up the `Ajax.BeginForm` instead of `OnComplete="onTestSuccess"`.

---

It turns out that the problem is with your controller action in which you specified incorrect Content-Type of `text/html`.

So instead of:

```
String uri = Url.Action("Confirm2", "Image", new RouteValueDictionary(new { category = "foo" })); 
return Json(new { success = true, uri = uri }, "text/html");
```

you should use:

```
String uri = Url.Action("Confirm2", "Image", new RouteValueDictionary(new { category = "foo" })); 
return Json(new { success = true, uri = uri });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am still not having much success.

Comment: see code: 

var uri = data.uri;
console.log(uri);

displays

LOG: undefined

Comment: @user1219694, you should use `OnSuccess="onTestSuccess"` instead of `OnComplete="onTestSuccess"` in your AjaxOptions.

Comment: Yes - that is what I am doing

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("create", "Guide", new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "Post",
                        OnSuccess = "JsonCreateGuide_OnComplete"
                    }))

Comment: And your controller action `return Json(new { uri = "/Image/Confirm2?category=foo" })`? You may also try `console.log($.parseJSON(data).uri);`.

Comment: String uri = Url.Action("Confirm2", "Image", new RouteValueDictionary(new { category = "foo" }));
return Json(new { success = true, uri = uri }, "text/html");

When I Console log data it appears that the data is returned back properly.  see 
LOG: data{"success":true,"uri":"/Image/Confirm2?category=foo"}

Comment: @user1219694, oh NO. Why did you set `text/html` as content type. That's just wrong. Remove this parameter and leave only `return Json(new { success = true, uri = uri })`. You are returning JSON, not HTML. That's why jQuery was enable to parse your response. Because you sent JSON but indicate wrong Content-Type header.

Comment: Thank You so much Darin - Fixed it!