# Receive JSON data within OnComplete event function in Ajax.Beginform

Tags: .net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use Ajax.BeginForm features.

The form is posted correctly, but I need to retrieve data in json format, from my controller action and refresh a **div** with the operation result message.

I have found several suggestions here in Stackoverflow, but none is useful.

Here is a suggestion found:

```
var data = content.get_response().get_object();
```

[But it didn't work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304233/how-to-use-ajax-beginform-mvc-helper-with-json-result). And I believe is deprecated up today, functional only for MVC 2 and lower versions.
My current **MVC** version is **3**.

Here is a piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function fnCompleted(data){
    if(data.Success)
    $("#somediv").html(data.StatusMessage).addClass("success");
    else
    $("#somediv").html(data.StatusMessage).addClass("error");
   }
</script>

@{
   var ajaxOptions= new AjaxOptions{
                    OnComplete= "fnCompleted",
                    Url= '@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")',
                    Method= "POST"
 }     

<div id="somediv">/*Here goes the json response*/</div>

using(Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxOptions)){

 @Html.EditorForModel()
 <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send">
```

}

Here is a piece of my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
 public JsonResult myAction(MyModel mymodel)
 {
  try
        {
            if (myModel== null)
                throw new Exception("The model is empty");
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                throw new Exception("The model is wrong");

            var found = /*Look for existence of the model in the database*/;
            if(found)
                throw new Exception("Already exists the object");

            /*Operation with the database*/

            var result = Json(
                new
                {
                    Success = true,//success
                    StatusMessage = "Object created successfully"
                });
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            var result = Json(
                new
                {
                    Success = false,//error
                    StatusMessage = exception.Message
                });
            return result;
        }
   }
```

Comment: add what you tried to your post

Comment: Please provide a code example so we can more clearly understand what you're describing. What have you tried? What worked? How far have you gotten? A JSFiddle would be ideal, and some example code from the Controller you're trying to call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The explanation that gains best interpretation for us could be that:

When we use OnComplete and JSON, the response is embedded directly to the DOM of the page. For that purposes instead it's recommended using OnSuccess and OnFailure. Those actually handle perfectly JSON results coming from a controller action.

I remit you guys to [The link that helped me, that was the same I ignored previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304233/how-to-use-ajax-beginform-mvc-helper-with-json-result), which I continued reading and found the **Joel Purra's** answer.

In your Ajax.BeginForm:

```
new AjaxOptions
{
    **OnFailure** = "onTestFailure",
    **OnSuccess** = "onTestSuccess"
}
```

Script block:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[

function onTestFailure(xhr, status, error) {

    console.log("xhr", xhr);
    console.log("status", status);       

    // TODO: make me pretty
    alert(error);
}

function onTestSuccess(data, status, xhr) {

    console.log("data", data);
    console.log("status", status);
    console.log("xhr", xhr);

    // Here's where you use the JSON object
    //doSomethingUseful(data);
}
```

Comment: data is not the actual data returned by my json action. It looks like xhr...? isntead to get the 'data' i need to to `data.responseText` and parseto json object. Still. good answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way of storing the result within the view OnComplete JS function?

ofcourse there are multiple ways to store the data recieved from by the controller I can suggest you to use a client side model something like  backbone.js model.

Using backbone.js model it is possible to store properly formatted JSON data objects and collections in client side.

Another way is using hidden browser variable small amount of data is feasible to store in hidden input control.

And another way is using a session based cookie.

Edit: if client side MVC like backbone.js used may be it might need to re-visit your current view design. But in the long run I think it is beneficial.